# Possible correction to Exercise $5.15$ in Rudin's Principles

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

Here's Exercise $5.15$ in Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis (Page $115$):

> Suppose $a \in \mathbb{R}^1$, $f$ is a twice-differentiable real function on  $(a,\infty)$, and $M_0$, $M_1$, $M_2$ are the least upper bounds of $|f(x)|$, $|f'(x)|$, $|f''(x)|$, respectively, on $(a,\infty)$. Prove that
>
> \begin{align*}
> M_1^2 \leq 4 M_0 M_2. 
> \end{align*}

Setting $a = 0$ and $f(x) = x$, we have $f'(x) = 1$, and $f''(x) = 0$, so

\begin{align*}
M_0 &= \sup_{x \in (0, \infty)} \{ x \} = \infty,
\\ M_1 &= \sup_{x \in (0, \infty)} \{ 1 \} =  1,
\\ M_2 &= \sup_{x \in (0, \infty)} \{ 0 \} = 0.
\end{align*}

In this case the inequality reads $1 \leq 4 \cdot \infty \cdot 0$, yet as Rudin comments after Theorem $4.34$ on page $98$, $\infty \cdot 0$ is not defined in the extended real numbers. To fix this, should we assume that $M_i$ is finite for $i = 0 , 1 , 2$?

Comment: I would understand from the statement that the $M_i$'s being finite is part of the assumptions.

Comment: This is discussed in "Littlewood's Miscellany". He gives a graphical proof which essentially draws a plot of f' and looks at its peak.

Comment: In chapter 1, Rudin mentions that least upper bounds are defined for bounded sets only.